# Is there any other (possibly less popular) approach to create AI apart from statistical methods?

Tags: machine-learning, reference-request, symbolic-ai, expert-systems, knowledge-based-systems

From what I have gathered so far, an AI has some prior (stored in the form of some probability distribution), and, based on experiences/data, changes the distribution (via Bayes rule) accordingly. This idea seems intuitively correct, as humans do something similar: we have some prejudice about certain things and refine it further based on additional observations.

I am wondering if there is a different (possibly, non-probabilistic) setting for designing an AI.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is *[symbolic AI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_artificial_intelligence)*. This was the 'original' approach to AI, at a time when there was very little data and/or processing power available. The focus was on logic and calculus, not on machine learning, which was just in its infancy.

A lot of natural language processing was developed using grammar rules (which only later were learned from data).

There still is a lot of this around, but often it's now hybrid, where human-authored rules correct the systematic mistakes of statistical approaches.

Update: as an example the Teneo system for building conversational agents (aka chatbots) uses both pattern matching rules and machine learning for intent recognition. The (human-created) patterns are more precise, but sometimes lack breadth of coverage, which the ML part provides, which works as a fallback.

Comment: It would be interesting if you could provide an example of a system that is hybrid, where the rules correct the statistical approaches. I know that some cognitive architectures are hybrid, but I don't remember the details or names. [This info](https://researcher.watson.ibm.com/researcher/view_group.php?id=10518) could be useful to answer this question.

Comment: @nbro Done! This is from a company I used to work for.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for are [Expert systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expert_system) and [Knowledge Based Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge-based_systems). Really similar to each other, they encompass all systems built upon experts knowledge, from which analytic rules are derived in order to allow their implementation in computer programs.

A trivial example could be a self driving system based on proximity sensors, a camera and a set of predefined rules (basically a set of explicit if-else statements) like:

- if value recorder from front proximity sensor < 10cm & left bottom corner of picture from camera is white (wall on the left) -> turn wheels 90 degrees to the right.
- if value recorder from front proximity sensor < 10cm & right bottom corner of picture from camera is white -> turn wheels 90 degrees to the left.
- ... (and so on and do forth)

Comment: I wouldn't limit the answer to this question to knowledge-based systems, but to **symbolic AI** (aka classical AI or GOFAI), which is the alternative approach to "statistical AI". This answer may not explicitly suggest that, for example, search algorithms (like A*) can be considered "AI algorithms".